# Uncaught TypeError: Immutable prototype object '#<Object>' cannot have their prototype set

Tags: javascript, prototype, typeerror

I have a .js file linked to a .htm file and the only code within the .js file is the line:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(Object.prototype,{x:616});
```

On loading the .htm page the "chrome console" displays the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Immutable prototype object '#<Object>' cannot have their prototype set
```

I've never seen this error before and can't find anything for it here or online.

I assumed that the object had been sealed/frozen, so ran the tests:

```
console.warn('sealed        ⇒',Object.isSealed(Object.prototype));      //  false
console.warn('frozen        ⇒',Object.isFrozen(Object.prototype));      //  false
console.warn('extensible    ⇒',Object.isExtensible(Object.prototype));  //  true
```

But this shed no light on the problem and as such has left me stumped. This is the first ever time that this has happened when setting the prototype of `Object.prototype` and has me wondering if my Chrome browser has auto-updated with new features or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is new in ES7 (aka ES2016). The builtin prototype object `Object.prototype` is now an [Immutable Prototype Exotic Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-immutable-prototype-exotic-objects) which has its `[[prototype]]` internal slot locked down.

It is supposed to [prevent proxies from being inserted in the global lookup mechanism](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/272), see [this commit](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/commit/935dad4283d045bc09c67a259279772d01b3d33d) for details. It has [recently been implemented in V8](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5149).

Comment: Why aren't extensions allowed to override this?

Comment: @Pacerier What do you mean by "extensions"? Browser extensions?