# How to extend the array with functions that are generators and able to chain them?

Tags: javascript, generator, chain

How do I extend Array with functions that returns a generator object and be able to chain them?

I have tried extending the Array to see if I can chain generator functions. The first call works, but the next chain would not, because it returns a generator object and I have no idea how to extend that.

```
Array.prototype.select = function* (fn) {
    let it = this[Symbol.iterator]();
    for (let item of it) yield fn(item);
}

Array.prototype.where = function* (fn) {
    let it = this[Symbol.iterator]();
    for (let item of it) {
        if (fn(item)) yield item;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to chain generators like this to an array

```
let result = arr.select(v => v * 2)
                .where(v => v % 3 === 0);

for (let item of result) console.log(item);
```

Comment: Why not use built-in methods? `arr.map(v => v * 2).filter(v => v % 3 === 0)`

Comment: Extending the prototype is a risky proposition. See [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/215552).

Comment: @adiga Im new to javascript and im experimenting how i can implement LINQ deferred execution. Im just curious with generators cause it reminds me of C# IEnumerator<> interface.

Comment: @adiga checkout this [repl](https://repl.it/@JeromeGamo/CaringGleamingFile) to see what Im trying to achieve.

Comment: @Kierkegaard I've already done [exactly this](https://github.com/patrickroberts/enumerable-ts). It's written in TypeScript but you can use it in node with JavaScript-only as it's pre-compiled. I do plan to update it soon to be umd format.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That is a really neat stuff you got there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying `Object`, you can still make these methods chainable by using a technique I've coined as ["superclassing"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51197642/1541563).

You start by defining your base class which `Array` will extend, then you modify the prototype chain of `Array` to artificially extend your base class.

Note how the `select()` and `where()` methods encapsulate your original generator functions to return new instances of the class so that the methods are chainable.

```js
class Enumerable {
  constructor (getIterator) {
    this[Symbol.iterator] = getIterator;
  }

  select (fn) {
    return new Enumerable(function * () {
      for (const value of this) {
        yield fn(value);
      }
    }.bind(this));
  }

  where (fn) {
    return new Enumerable(function * () {
      for (const value of this) {
        if (fn(value)) yield value;
      }
    }.bind(this));
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Array, Enumerable);
Object.setPrototypeOf(Array.prototype, Enumerable.prototype);

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const result = array
  .select(v => v * 2)
  .where(v => v % 3 === 0);

for (const item of result) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: Wow nice! I'm going to use this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could store both methods as a prototype function of `Object` and handover the iterator object, because both functions take a generator and returns an iterable object.

```js
Object.prototype.select = function* (fn) {
    for (let v of this) yield fn(v);
}

Object.prototype.where = function* (fn) {
    for (let v of this[Symbol.iterator]()) if (fn(v)) yield v;
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    result = array[Symbol.iterator]()
        .select(v => v * 2)
        .where(v => v % 3 === 0);

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about the Object, I am too caught up with translating c# inheriting to a specific class i need to extend. But is there a more specific way? or I should not make it complicated?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind overextending, the first iterator returns just an object.
You can check by doing `console.log(typeof arr.select(v => v * 2));`.

Hence, you can simply define: `Object.prototype.where = function* (fn) {};`

```js
Array.prototype.select = function* (fn) {
    let it = this[Symbol.iterator]();
    for (let item of it) {
      yield fn(item);
    }
};

Object.prototype.where = function* (fn) {
    let it = this[Symbol.iterator]();
    for (let item of it) {
        if (fn(item)) yield item;
    }
};


const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let result = arr.select(v => v * 2)
                .where(v => v % 3 === 0);

for (let item of result) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

If you want that the order does not matter, you could extend both Array and Object like this.

```js
Array.prototype.select = function* (fn) {
        let it = this[Symbol.iterator]();
        for (let item of it) {
          yield fn(item);
        }
    };

Array.prototype.where = function* (fn) {
    let it = this[Symbol.iterator]();
    for (let item of it) {
        if (fn(item)) yield item;
    }
};

Object.prototype.select = Array.prototype.select;
Object.prototype.where = Array.prototype.where;


const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// Chain 1.
let result1 = arr.select(v => v * 2).where(v => v % 3 === 0);

console.log('Chain 1');
for (const item of result1) {
  console.log(item);
}

// Chain 2.
let result2 = arr.where(v => v % 3 === 0).select(v => v * 2);

console.log('Chain 2')
for (const item of result2) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: FYI, `typeof` is an operator, not a function, so you can just do `typeof arr.select(v => v * 2)` without the parentheses.

Comment: Good catch. Updated. Thanks @HereticMonkey